# How can I use variables and double quotes?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string that contain variables I need to be able to keep the double quotes in the output of my printed string.

I need to be able to do this without using single quotes

Yal is the variable

```py
button = {"type" : "Push", "YAL" : "True"}
print(button)
```

output needs to be: `{"type" : "Push", "YAL" : "True"}`

I need the Variable YAL to the double quotes in the output

Comment: That is just the way Python represents its strings. If you want to format them differently, you're going to have to make a custom dictionary `__repr__` function.

Comment: Please rephrase. It is not at all clear what you want. Is the first sentence actually two sentences? Is Yal and YAL the same thing? What does "to the double quotes" mean? Perhaps try giving some example input and desired output.

Comment: Oh, just realised you might mean "dict" everywhere you say "string" in your question. Doesn't explain the YAL bit, but everything else would make a bit more sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative `dict.__repr__` function:

```py
def _repr(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        return '"' + obj + '"'
    return repr(obj)

def _dict_repr(D):
    items = map(lambda item: f'{_repr(item[0])}: {_repr(item[1])}', D.items())
    return '{' + ', '.join(items) + '}'
```

This should work for almost everything :D